# Python dictionary types as instance variables

Tags: python

I think I am going mad. I did the following in the repel (python3):

```
class aClass():
  da = {}

>>> a = aClass()
>>> b = aClass()
>>> a.da['T'] = 'Hello'
>>> print(a.da)
{'T': 'Hello'}
>>> print(b.da)
{'T': 'Hello'}
>>>
```

a and b are two different instances of the same class. I assigned something to a, why is it appearing in b?

I did the same but with a string type, no problem at all.

The following works:

```
>>> a={}
>>> b={}
>>> print(a)
{}
>>> print(b)
{}
>>> a['x']='x'
>>> print(a)
{'x': 'x'}
>>> print(b)
{}
```

but, that's exactly the same thing isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`aClass.da` is a class attribute, not an instance attribute. `a.da` and `b.da` are the same dictionary.

Create the dictionary in an `__init__` method instead.

```
class aClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.da = {}
```

(In Python 2, that should be `class aClass(object):` instead.)

Result:

```
>>> a = aClass()
>>> b = aClass()
>>> a.da['T'] = 'Hello'
>>> print(a.da)
{'T': 'Hello'}
>>> print(b.da)
{}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will mark as right once it allows me. (I saw https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables as well)